# Hibernate OneToMany/ManyToOne Delete Cascade

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to create a OneToMany/ManyToOne relation. All is working as expected except the delete operation, meaning, when a OwningSide is deleted, the NonOwningSide is deleted as well.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior, so if a OwningSide is deleted, the NonOwningSide's owningSide_id will be set to NULL?

Pseudo-code

```
public class OwningSide {

  @OneToMany(
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
      mappedBy = "owningSide")
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @JsonManagedReference  
  private List<NonOwningSide> nonOwningSide;

}

public class NonOwningSide {

  @ManyToOne(
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
      fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "owningSide_id")
  @JsonBackReference
  private OwningSide owningSide;

}
```

Comment: Sure. Don't use cascade = ALL which precisely tell Hibernate to do what you don't want. And make sure no NonOwningSide refers to the owningSide before deleting it.

Comment: If I remove CascadeType.ALL from the OwningSide, then the NonOwningSide's owningSide_id will remain NULL on create/update operations.

Comment: Cascading is not what populates the NonOwningSide's owningSide field. Bu anyway, Not using cascade = ALL doesn't mean you can't use **any** cascading. There are many other value in the CascadeType annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change **cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST** at own side.

```
public class OwningSide {

  @OneToMany(
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, mappedBy = "owningSide")
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @JsonManagedReference  
  private List<NonOwningSide> nonOwningSide;

}

public class NonOwningSide {

  @ManyToOne(
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "owningSide_id")
  @JsonBackReference
  private OwningSide owningSide;

}
```

CascadeType in JPA.
The value `cascade=ALL` is equivalent to
 * `cascade={PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH}`.

```
/** Cascade all operations */
ALL,

/** Cascade persist operation */
PERSIST,

/** Cascade merge operation */
MERGE,

/** Cascade remove operation */
REMOVE,

/** Cascade refresh operation */
REFRESH
```

To do this, When you are creating table and adding foreign key to NonOwningSide, Please mention cascade type as set null for deletion of owningSide as given below.

-- This time, create it with **on delete set null**:

```
alter table NonOwningSide add constraint constraintName 
foreign key (id) references OwningSide(id) on delete set null
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to set cjild's object as null explicitly

```
for (NonOwningSide child : OwningSide.getChildren()) {
child.setNonOwningSide(null);
```

}
session.delete(OwningSide);